google cloud storage data & google earth engine
I am currently facing a permission issue when trying to access data from Google Cloud Storage within Google Earth Engine. Despite setting what I thought were the correct permissions, I continue to receive an error indicating insufficient access.
I am attempting to load a geo-referenced TIFF image from a GCS bucket into my Google Earth Engine script for environmental analysis purposes. The aim is to process this image using Earth Engine's powerful geospatial processing capabilities.
